# maximum memory allocation for a local variable

Tags: java, variables, local

In Java, is a **local** variable allocated a maximum memory space of 32 bits? If it is, what happens if I use a local variable of data type long (64 bits) in a method in my java code? In **what way** would memory be allocated to this variable?

Whenever i googled to get an answer, I got explanations related only to java memory area which explained where (in the frame of the concerned method in stack..*that is OK i know this*) a local variable gets memory which is certainly not a relevant response to my query.

Comment: Local primitive variables are allocated on the stack.  What else do you need to know? Your question is unclear.

Comment: The Java [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.1) leaves room to implement things like that on purpose. All you should know as a Java programmer is that a `long` is a 64bit signed number regardless of the platform that exists in memory while it is in scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original VM specification is actually really messed up with regards to local variables, each local variable is reseved a "slot" on the stack (simply an index number) and each slot is supposed to hold 4 bytes. So each variable is mapped to one "slot". But variables that occupy more than 4 bytes (double, long) need to occupy *two consecutive* slots. References do occupy *one slot* however, although they may be 8 bytes on a 64 bit VM. There was no 64 bit VM when this was specified, hence the specification assumed 32 bit references.

In practice, I'm pretty sure any current VM will remap the stack slots as it sees fit and the actual size reserved on the stack will also be decided by the VM. So all that remains is a peculiar slot allocation scheme in the byte code, all that actual "slot" stuff is purely on the bytecode level - the VM doesn't need to physically adhere to the slot layout the bytecode specified.

Take a look into the bytecode specification: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/Overview.doc.html#17257

Answer (score 2):

JVMs usually word-align local variables on the stack, which means that they take up 32 bits on a 32 bit JVM (except for `long`s and `double`s, which will take up 64 bits) and that they will take up 64 bits on a 64 bit JVM.  The JVM is allowed to pack the variables so that they take up less space (e.g. putting 4 `byte`s in a 32 bit word rather than putting 4 `byte`s in 4 separate words), but this is slower than having all of the variables be word aligned since the processor will have to unpack them before using them.